# Preloading a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `preloadme` script to `fadeOut` my preloader `div` on `window.load` but I'm wondering if instead of waiting for the whole entire page to load I can target one specific div:

`preloadme` code

```
$(window).load(function() { 
$('#status').fadeOut(); 
$('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
$('body').delay(350);
})
```

my idea that doesn't work

`$('#img-container').load(function() {`

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid its not possible, since you can access the page `element` once `DOM` is initialize.

just go with `$(function(){ //your code})`, that will make your code run every time

```
$(function(){ 
   $('#status').fadeOut(); // dont rely on this to hide the loaded, use css below 
   $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
});
```

You can do this using CSS, to initially show the preloaded till page loads

```
#preloader {display:block}
```